# VueJS SPA routing is not working with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to build SPA and I need to make axios call to endpoint in my routes. How can make this api call work?

Here are my routes

```
Route::get('/{any}', function () {
    return view('default');
})->where('any', '.*');

Route::get('events', 'EventsController@index')->prefix('api');
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: you can check laravel and vuejs single page https://github.com/Kamleshpaul/blog

Answer (score 0):

use this

```php
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return view('default');
})
->where('all', '^(?!api).*$')
->where('all', '^(?!storage).*$');


Route::get('events', 'EventsController@index')->prefix('api');
```

as you will need `api` and `storage` route handel by laravel

Answer (score 0):

You must go to the folder routes->api and create your api routes, there is automatically the api prefix.

in your .vue

```
axios.get('/api/getUser')
     .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
      });
```

in your folder routes->api

```
Route::get('/getUser', 'Api\UsersController@getUser');
```

To not put "/api" in front of all your axios calls in your '.vue' you can put

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = '/api';
```

in your app.js

Answer (score 0):

We define a catch-all route to the SpaController which means that any web route will map to our SPA. If we didn’t do this, and the user made a request to /hello, Laravel would respond with a 404.

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Remember that this route will always be putted on the last part of your web routes after declaring your other routes